# Почему перестает работать v-on:click после подключения vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добрый день, начал делать новый проект на vuejs2, но столкнулся со странной проблемой.
Использую этот шаблон: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple
плюс добавляю vue-router: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/app.js

без роутера все работает как надо, но как только подключаю роутер, то перестает работать onclick ивент, сам роутер при этом работает. ошибок никаких не выкидывает, просто перестает работать. Куда смотреть и как это пофиксить?

UPD:
Я таки тупой. 
в App.vue у меня так:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <hello></hello>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import hello from './components/hello/Hello.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    hello
  }
}
</script>
<style>...</style>
```

и если в hello.vue в шаблоне выставить любую кнопку с onclick, то она не будет работать если компонент подключен таким способом. И заработает если подключить тот же самый hello.vue в роутер вот так:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import hello from './components/hello/Hello.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/hello',
    name: 'hello',
    component: hello
  },
];

var router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes
});

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

потому вопрос меняется: как сделать так, что бы можно было подключать компоненты не в роутере(и что бы они работали)? например в данном случае мне нужно что бы этот hello.vue был на всех страницах, потому он подключен в app.vue но там он работает неправильно.

Comment: а пример кода, который не работает?

Comment: <button v-on:click="doSomething">Do it!</button>

Comment: Это Здорово, пример бы из контекста, ты точно задал контейнер ? для инициализации vue, и точно ли кнопка лежит в нем ?

Comment: Весь остальной код по ссылкам выше я в нем ничего практически не менял, только добавил одну кнопку и все. Без роутера кнопка работает, включаю роутер - он работает, кнопка - нет.

Comment: Хорошо, а как и где ты расположил обработку onclick ? пример

Comment: Добавил код, нашел где проблема, но не понял почему она ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин.. во я идиот.. все было очень просто, нужно было заменить этот кусок кода:

```
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

на

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: function(createElement){
        return createElement(App)
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

и всё работает.